# Left join in Django model query?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I want to use left join of mysql query in django model query.

MY mysql query that I want to use is:

```
select U.id, B.id as boardId, count(BJ.id) as countBoardMember,
       count(NM.id) as newsCountInBaord
from users as U
left join boards as B on B.userId = U.id
left join board_join as BJ on B.id = BJ.boardId
left join news_mappings as NM on NM.boardId = B.id
where B.isArchived = false
group by B.id
having countBoardMember < 10 and newsCountInBaord < 5
limit 10
```

But what Django model query is making is using left outer join and then inner join:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, COUNT(`board_join`.`joinedBy`) AS `countBoardMember`,
       COUNT(`news_mappings`.`id`) AS `newsCountInBaord`
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `boards` ON (`users`.`id` = `boards`.`userId`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `board_join` ON (`boards`.`id` = `board_join`.`boardId`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news_mappings` ON (`boards`.`id` = `news_mappings`.`boardId`)
INNER JOIN `boards` T6 ON (`users`.`id` = T6.`userId`)
INNER JOIN `board_join` T7 ON (T6.`id` = T7.`boardId`)
WHERE (T7.`requestStatus` = approved AND T6.`isArchived` = False)
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
HAVING (COUNT(`board_join`.`joinedBy`) > 10 AND COUNT(`news_mappings`.`id`) > 5)
ORDER BY NULL limit 10;
```

It is taking much longer time to achive my result.

My django model query is this:

```
user_ids = (
    Users.objects.using('cms')
    .annotate(countBoardMember=Count('boards__boardjoin__joinedBy'),
              newsCountInBaord=Count('boards__newsmappings__id'))
    .filter(boards__isArchived=0, boards__boardjoin__requestStatus='approved', 
            countBoardMember__gt=10, newsCountInBaord__gt=5).all()
)
```

What I am doing wrong in my Django model query?

Comment: You could use raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Outer joins are created because fields "newsmappings", "joinedBy" and "boardjoin" may be null.

You can do one of the following:

1. Delete "null=True" in models boards, board_join, news_mappings to thees fields can't bu null
2. Add filters to the query to exclude empty entries. As example:

   ```
   user_ids = (
   Users.objects.using('cms')
   .annotate(countBoardMember=Count('boards__boardjoin__joinedBy'),
             newsCountInBaord=Count('boards__newsmappings__id'))
   .filter(boards__isArchived=0, boards__boardjoin__requestStatus='approved', 
           countBoardMember__gt=10, newsCountInBaord__gt=5,
           boards__isnull=False, boards__boardjoin__isnull=False,
           boards__newsmappings__isnull=False).all()
   )
   ```